# history.push() redirects on hard-coded path, but not with the one provided by state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have the following private route, which when attempted to access by unauthorized user, redirects user to Login component (see below).

```
<PrivateRoute path="/checkout/step1" component={Address} />
```

The code for `PrivateRoute` is the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

In my Login component I want to redirect user back to the private route, after successful login:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      path: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let pathname = "/";
    // need try-catch, since 
    // this.props.history.location.state.from.pathname
    // might be inaccessible resource
    try {
      pathname = this.props.history.location.state.from.pathname;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Resource inaccessible.");
    }
    this.setState({ path: pathname });
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // authentication
    this.props.onAuth(this.state.email, this.state.password);

    // this.props.history.push(this.state.path); // not working
    // this.props.history.push("/about"); // working fine
  };

  renderLoginForm = token => {
    // ... skipped
  };

  render() {
    const { token } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.renderLoginForm(token)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The `pathname` in try-catch block gets a proper value, when user attempts to access the private route and defaults to `/` in the case user wants to login, coming from the regular route.

I have this weird problem that `this.props.history.push()` redirects properly for hard-coded path, but for the path from the state it simply redirects to `/`. I couldn't find the answer to this particular problem.

This might be irrelevant for this question, but let me just mention that both components `Login` and `Address` are connected to Redux store.

Answer (score 0):

Since this.setState is triggered asynchronously you should put it inside the try catch in your case:

```
componentDidMount() {
let pathname = "/";
// need try-catch, since 
// this.props.history.location.state.from.pathname
// might be inaccessible resource
try {
  pathname = this.props.history.location.state.from.pathname;
  this.setState({ path: pathname });
} catch (err) {
  console.log("Resource inaccessible.");
  this.setState({ path: pathname });
}   
}
```

You could also do this in a cleaner way using async function with if statement to evaluate if this.props.history... exists. Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Also, could you elaborate a bit more about this async function perhaps? Thank you.